# How do I fix "Exceeded maximum execution time" error on this Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout

I want to devise a script that will clean up my email.  I want to create a few labels called "Auto Archive/# days" where # is a number between 0 and 9.  I wrote this script below, but every time it runs, I receive an "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.

I have a time-driven (hour timer) trigger set up to run every 12 hours.  I call the `autoArchive` method in the trigger.  I tried adding `Utilities.sleep` a few times, but it didn't help.  [Should I put them somewhere else in the code?]

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

```
function cleanUp(delayDays) {
//var delay2Weeks = 14 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to archive
//var delay2Days = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to archive

  if (typeof delayDays != 'number') {
    return null;
  }

  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Auto Archive/" + delayDays + " days");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
    {
      var randnumber = Math.random()*5000;
      Utilities.sleep(randnumber);
      Utilities.sleep(randnumber);
      threads[i].moveToArchive();
    }
  }
}


function autoArchive()
{
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     cleanUp(i); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I was getting all items with "Auto Archive/X days" and not limiting the result set to only items within the Inbox.  After correcting that, the maximum execution time error went away.  I corrected it by choosing the inbox items first, and next the items with the label.

```
function cleanUp(delayDays) {
//var delay2Weeks = 14 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to archive
//var delay2Days = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to archive

  if (typeof delayDays != 'number') {
    return null;
  }

  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);

  var inboxItems = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < inboxItems.length; i++) {
      if (inboxItems[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate) {
        var autoItems = inboxItems[i].getLabels();
        for(var j=0; j < autoItems.length; j++) {
          if (autoItems[j].getName() == "Auto Archive/" + delayDays + " days") {
            inboxItems[i].moveToArchive();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }  

}


function autoArchive()
{
  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     cleanUp(i); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to speed it up. For starters dont call sleep as it will make the problem worse (makes the script take even more time from your daily quota and trigger 5min limit).
After that if the problem is that you have too many threads it might help to write a list of threads to archive (in scriptdb for example store the thread ids) but dont archive them yet.
Later from another trigger (say every 10min) you process your list by chunks (see  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getThreadById(String)) and use more triggers if needed to avoid the 5min limit.

Comment: I removed the "Utilities.sleep()" methods and then Google reported this error to me:  Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 20, file "Code")

The following line is line 20:
threads[i].moveToArchive();

I'm still looking into your other suggestion about breaking out the process.

Comment: yes, I suspected you put the sleep in there to prevent the "too many times" error, but as you can see that suggestion is really more of a hack that can get you into other problems like consuming your 5minute quota per run. after you break out the process, you will still need the sleeps but it wont matter since the next trigger run will continue the moving.

Comment: I didn't end up breaking out the process into a separate function.  Instead I limited my query to only items in the Inbox (see associated answer).  Thank you for your recommendations - starting to break it out lead me to thinking about the fact it was pulling all items having the Auto Archive labels and that this was a problem.